# How to create a virtual application and directories in azure website programmatically

Tags: c#, azure

We use Windows Azure website management library and create a web app programmatically by using C# code but we cannot create a virtual directory inside a web app. please help me how to create virtual directory inside a web app programmatically 
My Code here

```
var websiteManagementClient = 
CloudContext.Clients.CreateWebSiteManagementClient(Credentials);


var webSpaces = websiteManagementClient.WebSpaces.List();
var webSpace = webSpaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GeoRegion == "South Central US");
if (webSpace == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("No webspace for region {0} found", "South Central US"));
}

var webHostingPlans = websiteManagementClient.WebHostingPlans.List(webSpace.Name);
var webHostingPlan = webHostingPlans.FirstOrDefault();
if (webHostingPlan == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("No webhostingplan found"));
}

try
{
    var website = websiteManagementClient.WebSites.Get(webSpace.Name, "MyAzureTestSite", null);

    if (website != null)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("The website {0} already exists", ""));
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}

var websiteCreateParams = new WebSiteCreateParameters();
websiteCreateParams.Name = "MyAzureTestSite";
websiteCreateParams.ServerFarm = webHostingPlan.Name;
websiteManagementClient.WebSites.Create(webSpace.Name, websiteCreateParams);
```

Comment: This throw followed by its own empty catch block looks kinda funny.

Answer (score 2):

At first I tried to create virtual directory with the help of Azure SDK but was not successful. Finally, I used http request to create it.

If you can use this method, you can check it out on my blog.

http://kapiltak.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-create-virtual-application-in.html

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Azure
    {
        private string loginpath = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
        private string apiEndpoint = "https://management.azure.com/";

        //Fill these up
        private string webSiteName = "{your webSiteName}";
        private string webSpaceName = "Default-Web-SoutheastAsia"; //Insert your webSpaceName here
        private string tenantId = "{your tenantId}";
        private string clientId = "{your client Id}";
        private string subscriptionId = "{your subscription Id}";

        //Not needed to set in console app because a function is called to get the token
        //string token = "";

        public void CreateVD(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format(@"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{2}/config/web?api-version=2015-08-01",subscriptionId,webSpaceName,webSiteName));
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-03-01");
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                var token = GetAuthorizationHeader();
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);

                System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                string data = "";
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
                    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("data found");
                }

                if (data == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error in collecting data");
                    return;
                }

                string path = name, directory = name;
                data = data.Replace("virtualApplications\":[", "virtualApplications\":[{\"virtualPath\":\"/" + path + "\",\"physicalPath\":\"site\\\\wwwroot\\\\" + directory + "\",\"preloadEnabled\":false,\"virtualDirectories\":null},");
                request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format(@"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{2}/config/web?api-version=2015-08-01",subscriptionId,webSpaceName,webSiteName));
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-03-01");
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                request.Accept = "Accept=application/json";
                request.SendChunked = false;
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                request.Method = "PUT";

                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                sw.Write(data);
                sw.Close();

                response = request.GetResponse();

                using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    data = (new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("DONE");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private string GetAuthorizationHeader()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(loginpath, tenantId));

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                result = context.AcquireToken(apiEndpoint, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri));
            });

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Name = "AquireTokenThread";
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            string token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be used to create virtual directory from website itself but you cannot use "GetAuthorizationHeader()" method to get the token. Instead you can get the token by running the console app once and use a breakpoint to get the string value. Use this value in the code and remove the "GetAuthorizationHeader()" method.

Comment: Links to external sites often "dry up" or disappear over time. If you have the answer to this person's question you should post the relevant code here and then leave the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll edit my post to include code.